# How to download the video descriptions of all my YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to download all video descriptions from my videos? Or at least to list them?

I need to make a copy of all the descriptions of more than 100 videos. Copy and pasting each one by hand seems to be a Sisyphean task.

Maybe someone knows a way to do this with their API, or a webservice that can help out?

Answer (score 1):

It indeed is possible via the API. You need your userId for this, you can get it via https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced.

What you then want to do in the API is call [`playlistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), with `part=snippet` and `playlistId=UUuserId` (note: the UU is not a typo, it's the "type indicator" of the playlist) and `maxresults` and `pagetoken` set appropriately.